# C++ create Object accesible by . operator on heap?

Tags: java, c++

this might be stupid question, but:

When I moved from ASM to C (no, I am not actually that old, I just started to love programing on MCU), I LOVED the way heap memory is used. Malloc was my friend, and I quickly became familiar with pointers. BUT...

Than I moved to OOP and Java. And actully, despite I don´t like Java as a runtime, I love its language. Now, I would like to combine both, speed and memory management capabilities of C and the beauty of OOP. So I started to learn C++.

My problem is, in Java I was used to access class members and functions with . operator. In C++, I have to use somehow not so nice and easy to type -> operator.

So, my question is, is there some way you can use . operator instead of -> to access class members of object allocated on heap? Becouse, stack is limited, and the true power of OOP is in dynamic creation of objects. Remaining "differences" are OK :) . Well, maybe C++ yould allow you to define class methods inside class, but no one can have everything, right? :D Thanks.

Comment: If you're using freestore allocation so often as to care about this one way or another, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: C++ _does_ allow you to define class methods inside the class definition.

Comment: In addition, stack is a great thing. If you don't appreciate it, then it's time to re-learn programming.

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't be allocating objects on the heap in C++ yourself. You should just make them automatic variables. Anything on the heap should be controlled by some kind of smart pointer such as `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

Comment: This is just silly. Wouldn't you rather just learn to do C++ properly?  Instead of trying to force one language to be like another.  I mean, what's the point?  Nobody is going to want to hire you if your programming style is silly and nonsensical.

Comment: Hi, long time not here, but finally... I DO appreciate automatic variables (stack allocation). I was JUST asking. I am not using it that much. And, as for defining methods, I probably read some wrong tutorial. Its just, I know on x86 systems, its common. But when programing for some MCU, you spend longer time managing memory yourself. I was asking just in case. I am just starting with objective C++. But what if, for example you would need to store some image in RAM directly? Its too large for heap, and also it would massivelly increased code size when set as global... Again, just learning :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Class &c = *c_ptr; // dereference pointer
```

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Just get a reference to some object allocated on the heap (or the stack, but that's beyond scope):

```
Object* my_obj_ptr = SomehowGetHeapObject();
Object& my_obj = *my_obj_ptr;
```

...then you can use the dot operator on the reference:

```
my_obj.Foo();
```

Perhaps a pertinent question would be, why is this throwing you off?

Answer (score 1):

In C++ there are two ways to access members of an object, depending upon how you are holding the object.  If you have the object directly (or have a reference to it), you use the dot operator, `.`. If you have a pointer to the object, you use the pointer operator `->`.

Consider:

```
class C;
...

// creates a new copy of "c" on stack
int f(C c) {
  c.something = c.else;
}
// creates a reference to caller's "c"
int f(C& c) {
  c.something = c.else;
}
// creates a pointer to caller's "c"
int f(C* p) {
  c->something = c->else;
}
```

So, your problem is this: you have a pointer, but you don't like the pointer operator. Frankly, I don't really see this as a problem, you should just use the pointer operator until you like it. But, this is SO, so here is a solution.

Initialize a reference from your pointer, and use the reference instead:

```
int f(C* p) {
  C& c = *p;
  c.something = c.else; // update the object pointed to by 'p'
}
```

Or, to make it feel even more natural:

```
int f2(C& c) {
  c.something = c.else; // updates f1's object
}
int f1() {
  C* p = new C;
  f2(*p);
  delete p; // don't forget this step!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not posssible, at least without some syntax changes. You can use (*Pointer).Function, which Pointer->Function is just a synonym for, but I think the latter is more comfirtable (that's  why it exists).

**EDIT:** Or as the other posts say, just store the dereferenced pointer in a reference. Haven't thought about that, as the whole question is a bit strange.